# Nested ANOVA in statsmodels

Tags: python, r, statsmodels, anova

**The issue:**

When trying to compute two-way nested ANOVA, the results do not equal the appropriate results from R (formulas and data are the same).

**Sample:**

We use "atherosclerosis" dataset from here: https://stepik.org/media/attachments/lesson/9250/atherosclerosis.csv.
To get nested data we replace dose values for age == 2:

```
df['dose'] = np.where((df['age']==2) & (df['dose']=='D1'),'D3', df.dose)
df['dose'] = np.where((df['age']==2) & (df['dose']=='D2'),'D4', df.dose)
```

So we have dose factor nested into age: values D1 and D2 are in first age and values D3 and D4 are only in the 2nd age.
After getting ANOVA table we have the results below:

```
mod = ols('expr~age/C(dose)', data=df).fit()
anova_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(mod, typ=1); anova_table
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s8li.png)

The total sum of the 'sum_sg' = 1590.257424 + 47.039636 + 197.452754 = 1834.7498139999998 that is NOT equal the right total sum (computed below) = 1805.5494956433238

```
grand_mean = df['expr'].mean()
ssq_t = sum((df.expr - grand_mean)**2)
```

**Expected Output:**

Let's try to get ANOVA table in R:

```
df <- read.csv(file = "/mnt/storage/users/kseniya/platform-adpkd-mrwda-aim-imaging/mrwda_training/data_samples/athero_new.csv") 
nest <- aov(df$expr ~ df$age / factor(df$dose))
print(summary(nest))
```

The results:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZbK8.png)

Why they are not equal? The formulas are the same. Are there any mistakes in computing ANOVA through statsmodels?

The results from R seem to be right, because the total sum 197.5 + 17.8 + 1590.3 = 1805.6 is equal to the total sum computed manually.

Comment: check if the OLS results has a column of zeros, `mod.model.exog`

Comment: It doesn't have

Comment: I found the solution there: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/8506 For right computing nested ANOVA in my example we should: 1) use same values of the nested factor within every level of the main factor (in my case D1 and D2 values in the dose field). 2) note that age factor is a categorical one, so use C(age) in the formula: expr~C(age)/C(dose) or even expr~C(age)/dose.   Only both conditions applied can give the right results (that are totally the same R gives)

Answer (score 0):

The degrees of freedom aren't equal. I suspect that the model definition is not really the same between OLS and R. Since `lm(y ~ x/z, data)` is just a shortcut for `lm(y ~ x + x:z, data)`, I prefer using the extended formulation and recheck if your data is the same. Use also `lm` instead of `aov` and . Behaviour of the Python and R implementations should be more similar.

Also behavior of `C()` in Python does not seem the same as `factor()` cast in R.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, using the extended formulation (both in python and R) does not change anything. Excluding C() and factor() too. The result sums of squares and degrees of freedom are the same and they are still not equal in R and python

Comment: Besides, lm() instead of aov() does not give sum of squares, that I need.

Comment: Degrees of freedom are not the same for each predictor (you get `df=3` in Python and `df=2` in R)

Comment: Yes, I see. I can't understand why? It seems to me that df=2 is right for the nested case, but why python gives df=3?